# Printing an input's digits each in a new line

Tags: java

First of all, i just started programming with Java so i'm really a noob :P

Ok so my instructor gave me an assignment which is to take an int input from the user and put each digit in a new line.
for example, if the user gave 12345, the program will give:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

each number in a new line.

The statements i will be using is IF statement and the loops and operators ofcourse.

I thought about using the % operator inside the IF/WHILE but i have two issues. One is that i don't know the number of digits the user is inputting and since i can't use the .length statement i reached a dead end. second of all the console output will be 5 4 3 2 1 inversed.

So can anyone help me or give me any ideas?

Comment: Please show us the code you have already tried.

Comment: you can convert the number to String

Answer (score 2):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewLineForDigit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please, enter any integer: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String intString = sc.next();
        for (char digit : intString.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the assignment your instructor gave you, can you convert the `int` into a `String`? With the input as a `String`, you can use the `length()` String function as you had mentioned to iterate the number of characters in the input and use the built-in `String` function `charAt()` to get the index of character you want to print. Something like this:

```
String input = 12345 + "";
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    System.out.println( input.charAt(i) );
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to get the users input as an `int` and converting that `int` to a `String` using [valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)). Lastly loop over the `String` to get the individual `digits` converting them back to `int's` from `char's` :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a Integer:");
    int input = sc.nextInt();

    String stringInput = String.valueOf(input);

    for(int i = 0; i < stringInput.length(); i++) {
      int j = Character.digit(stringInput.charAt(i), 10);
      System.out.println(j);
    }
  }
}
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/EvTT/1)